# Run docker container after the other container exits

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have following docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  serviceA:
    image: my/serviceA
    container_name: serviceA
  serviceB:
    image: my/serviceB
    container_name: serviceB
```

I want to run serviceB container after serviceA container exits.
Is there any way to wait for serviceA to exit and then run container serviceB?

Answer (score 3):

You could potentially configure a script on the second container to ping the first, a little like https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ but checking the container is down instead of up.

However from experience that is a little error prone.  I prefer to run docker-compose twice.  Assuming the first container exits after command has been executed you could run `serviceA` without the daemon flag `-d` then run serviceB

```
docker-compose up serviceA
docker-compose up -d serviceB
```

You can put these commands in a script if that is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the `depends_on`.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  serviceA:
    image: my/serviceA
    container_name: serviceA
  serviceB:
    image: my/serviceB
    container_name: serviceB
    depends_on:
      serviceA:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
```

See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on

Comment: I totally agree with jacquev6, it´s a life saver when having slow running jobs in in this case serviceA.

Answer (score 1):

Docker Compose doesn't support this.

There's a more-or-less [standard trick](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) for service B to wait for service A to *start*.  If one service has a way to see the other (for instance, service A is running a network service that's visible on the private Docker network) then service B could wait for A to start, then wait for B to stop, then do its work.  You won't be able to see if A exited successfully, though.

If you're comfortable giving service B potentially unrestricted root access on the host, you could mount the Docker socket into its container, and then it could watch for service A to exit.  It might be cleaner to right some orchestrator service C that started A, saw it exit, then started B.

(If you were in Kubernetes, it has a [pre-stop hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) which can run a script in service A before it exits, but that's a pretty heavy-weight answer.)